# posting to a controller action in a different application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, post

How can I post to a controller action in a different application? Are there any alternatives besides a web service?

I'd heard there is an attribute which I can use to make this happen, but I am unable to find it anywhere.

Comment: Here is one way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: why would you want to do this? assuming the two applications are just sharing a method for processing some data, that would seem to be an ideal candidate for moving the code into something like a webservice.